# How do I deal with occlusion, warping, or perspective distortion for object detection?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am using SIFT features for detecting logos in clothes. SIFT is quite powerful, as it is scale invariant, but how do I deal with the problem of occlusion and warping?

More specifically, the logos in clothes might be partially occluded, and can also be warped when the clothes are stretched or squeezed.

Any suggestion and directions? Thanks in advance!

Some example are showed here:

Logo on leg:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your performance with SIFT-only is bad, I'd probably try and input the features you've got into a machine learning algorithm. There's lots of approaches, here's one for a start: http://ccc.inaoep.mx/~emorales/Papers/2010/leonardo.pdf Another idea would be to update your database with partial/3d-rotated logos (only viable if you're not detecting many different types of logos)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there are more than 200 types of logos.

Comment: Can't help you - but good question including the illustrative pics.

Comment: @kim all the more reason to read into ML ;)

Answer (score 0):

[bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) is your answer. It skips an affine transform confirming a proper alignment of your SIFT points and uses only their descriptors to confirm their identities. The price you pay - you will need more points to confirm a logo.

On top of that you can write your own spatial consistency validation routine since even when affine transform is a bad fit to your distorted images the basic ordering constraints (what’s on the right, left, bottom and top) should still be valid.

Comment: thanks for your answer. For bag of words method, 1). do I need to specifically choose images to learn the dictionary? i.e. images containing different types of logos, and with each logo under different situations such as with different size, view point, occlusion?     2). Bag of words method works to find similar images, but what if the size proportion of the logo in image is quite small, like the third image in my post, and the obtained histogram representation may not reflect that logo as it is too small compared to the whole image.  Will BOW still work in this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Remember that SIFT is scale invariant, right? And yes you need to specify the images to learn the dictionary which I believe would consist of most common classes of descriptors. Use K-means to find he words during learning; then assign each descriptor to the nearest cluster to find the ‘word’ during recognition.The bag of words descriptor is simply a histogram with the frequencies of different “words” regardless of their position. Finally, since you are going to loose your spatial information it will be hard to localize the logo or even to decide how many of what logos is there.